# How to read character by character from a file to a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to read character from a text file that looks like this. The '-' are supposed to be converted to zeros and the 'x' are supposed to be converted to ones

```
3
3
-x-
xx-
--x
```

I'm able to read the first two integers using a seperate function but when I use this method to copy it over I get a 3x6 2d array with all zeros. the output is

```
0 0 0
0 0 0 
0 0 0 
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

Comment: We might be better able to explain what's wrong with your code if you actually include it in the question.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Answer (score 1):

To read character by character from a file, you have some options.

**Character by character**

```
char c;
ifstream data_file("my_file.txt");
while (data_file >> c)
{
  Do_Something_With_Character(c);
}
```

**By text line**
From your input data example, you may want to read text line instead:

```
std::string text;
ifstream data_file("my_file.txt")
while (getline(data_file, text))
{
  for (int index = 0; index < text.length(); ++i)
  {
    Do_Something_With_Character(text[index]);
  }
}
```

Note:  The above examples are generic for reading data.  They do not parse the OP's input file.